# Higher Dimensional Paley Wiener Theorem

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis

Is there a natural generalization of the Paley Wiener theorem to higher dimensions (i.e. relating a function $f \in L^2(K), K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ compact, to an entire function in $\mathbb{C}^d$)? If so, where can I find a statement/proof of such a theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reed/Simon, Functional analysis, chapter IX, Theorem IX.11. It can also be found somewhere in Rudin's book.

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome